# One data.json accessed and changed by multiple sources

Tags: javascript, java, json, node.js, filewriter

My goal is the use the data in a JSON file ("data.json") for both my Java application and my node.js application.

Java application reads the JSON file and rewrites the file, only with additional or edited JSON objects.

I would like also the node.js application to read the JSON file and rewrite the file with additional or edited JSON objects.

What is the best way to do this? What are my options for collaborating, syncing and queuing changes from each source?

Thanks

Comment: @Archer this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

Obviously to protect the file from corruption on concurrent writes and reads you need to implement some lock system. Between the threads in a single process it's a trivial task, however between processes it's not that easy.

There's one trick that could work on UNIX systems and it's based on the fact that file rename procedure is atomic in unix. Based on the file renaming you could implement a simple mutex, or even a more complicated read-write lock semantics. For a simple mutex use the following strategy:

1. When an app want's to use the file, check the `data*` file name. If    it's `data_locked_<some_pid>`, wait (or subscribe to FS notifications so that you don't need to poll FS and spend CPU time) and repeat step 1.
2. If the file name is `data` attempt to rename the file to `data_locked_<pid>`. If the attempt succeed - use the file.
3. After you finish working with the file rename it back to `data`

This simple mutex semantics will keep the file locked for use by a single process, however, reading operations be safely performed concurrently, so you could optimise the solution further by making a ReadWriteLock:

For reads:

1. When the app whats to read the file, check if the file name is `data` or `data_readlocked_<some_pid_list>`. Attempt to rename the file to `data_readlocked_<original_pid_list + pid>`. If attempt failed, repeat step 1.
2. Read the file.
3. Rename the file so that it's name doesn't contain this process pid any more. If this process pid is the only in the list - rename to `data`. If rename attempt failed repeat step 3 until attempt is succeed.

For write:

1. Check if the file name if `data`. If it is, rename to `data_writelocked_<pid>`, if failed repeat step 1. If the file name is anything other then `data` - wait and repeat step 1.
2. Write to the file.
3. Rename it back to `data`.

Comment: What do you mean by "If it's lock", please

Comment: @Zodzie oh, sorry, I've edited the answer but forgot to update this piece. Edited now, should be clear.